# Wordpress - Contact form 7 não funciona com o DOM do jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dom

Tenho esse código que traz documentos via DOM para a página

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.abas').on('click', function(){
        var paginas = ["pagina1.html","pagina2.html","pagina3.html"];
        aba_index = $(this).attr('tabindex');
        $('.abas').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).load("caminho/"+paginas[parseInt(aba_index) - 1]);
    });
});
```

Dentro dessas páginas, tem um formulário que o html é esse

```
<form action="/#wpcf7-f6-p1065-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate>
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="6">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9.2">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f6-p1065-o1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="1065">
</div>
<div class="digite_email">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email"><input type="text" name="email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail"></span>
</div>
<div class="assinar">
<input type="submit" value="saber mais" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
</div>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>
```

Por exemplo:

Quando abro a pagina1.html via DOM, o formulario não funciona, acredito que seja porque o Plugin Contact form 7 usa o jquery para enviar os formulários.

Como posso fazer funcionar via DOM o Contact-form-7 do wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

O ideial é você envolver o seu script assim:

`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.abas').on('click', function(){
        var paginas = ["pagina1.html","pagina2.html","pagina3.html"];
        aba_index = $(this).attr('tabindex');
        $('.abas').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).load("caminho/"+paginas[parseInt(aba_index) - 1]);
    });
  });
});`

Acho que fazendo isso vai resolver seu problema.

Comment: não deu certo ainda @digo ribeiro

Comment: Tá online seu site?
Manda o link.